# pandas return error when combining a series with a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, data-manipulation

I am trying to combine a series with a dataframe (column-wise):

```
xray_XY_ok =  pd.concat([xray[xray.columns[0]], xray_X_ok], axis=1, ignore_index = True)
```

but I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7808, 51), indices imply (6496, 51)
```

but the two datas' shapes are of the following:

```
xray_X_ok.shape
(5856, 50)
xray[xray.columns[0]].shape
(5856,)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: My *guess* is that your index isn't unique, so it's ambiguous how the dataframes should align